# Set new id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

"this" is a text field, "new_id" is an integer.

When I apply the following snippet:

```
$(this).attr('id',   this.id + '_' + new_id);
$(this).attr('name', this.name + '_' + new_id);
$(this).attr('value', 'test');
```

the id changes, the name changes too, but not the value. If I change the last line to this (and therefore use a string literal)

```
$('#mytextfield_3').attr('value', 'test');
```

it works.

Any ideas?

-- EDIT --
Thanks to Steerpike for the quick plugin test - i believe it should work, but i can't find the error.

Here's some more code:

I create the clone using

```
clone = $(this).find('.clone_fields_container:first').clone();
```

"clone" now contains a div which has embedded input fields.

After generating a new id:

```
  /** Iterate over input and select fields in container */

  clone.children('input,select,textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id',   this.id + '_' + new_id);
    $(this).attr('name', this.name + '_' + new_id);
    $(this).val('test');
    console.log(this);
  });
```

The text fields do not have any values.

Comment: is the id still unique for the document after you've changed it?

Comment: yes, after i changed it, it's unique

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just wrote a quick plugin to run a test using your same snippet and it works fine

```
$.fn.test = function() {
      return this.each(function(){
        var new_id = 5;
        $(this).attr('id',   this.id + '_' + new_id);
        $(this).attr('name', this.name + '_' + new_id);
        $(this).attr('value', 'test');
      });
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field_id').test()
});

<body>
  <div id="container">

  <input type="text" name="field_name" id="field_id" value="meh" />
  </div>
</body>
```

So I can only presume something else is going on in your code. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: You were right, after half a night of debugging i found that it's not good to mix .html() editing with direct node manipulation... anyway, your code brought me to the solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
$(this).val('test');
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr('value', 'test');
```

`val()` is generally easier, since the attribute you need to change may be different on different DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: based on your comment and assuming that `this` is the element that is cloned.

```
 $(this).clone()
        .attr( 'id', this.id + '_' + new_id )
        .attr( 'name', this.name + '_' + new_id )
        .val( 'test' )
        .appendTo('#someElement');
```

**Full Example**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var new_id = 0;
    $(document).ready( function() {
       $('#container > input[type=button]').click( function() {
            var oldinp = $('input#inp')[0];
            var newinp = $(oldinp).clone()
                                  .attr('id',oldinp.id + new_id )
                                  .attr('name',oldinp.name + new_id )
                                  .val('test')
                                  .appendTo($('#container'));
            $('#container').append('<br>');
            new_id++;
        });
     });
 </script>


 <div id="container">
 <input type="button" value="Clone" /><br/>
 <input id="inp" name="inp" type="text" value="hmmm" /><br/>
 </div>
```

Comment: @TStamper: yes, i understood, but this does not work.
@tvanfosson: Changing the value before the id does not work here, because the form element is a clone of another element, so first it has to get a unique id.

Comment: @schneck -- I've updated my answer with respect to cloning an element.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you set all of the attributes in one [`attr()` command](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) like so

```
$(this).attr({
               id : this.id + '_' + new_id,
               name: this.name + '_' + new_id,
               value: 'test' 
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` not `attr('value')`.