# Removing DOM and add it back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, detach

I have a simple JS function that removes certain classes while clicking on a "filter menu". The problem is that I don't know how to show those removed classes once I click on "All" i.e.

I can't use `display:none`, `opacity:0` or `visibility:hidden`, I need to completely remove the DOM.

Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document).on("click",".all",function(){$(".campaign,.editorial,.lookbook,.portrait").appendTo("body")})
$(document).on("click",".cam",function(){$(".editorial,.lookbook,.portrait").detach()})
$(document).on("click",".edi",function(){$(".campaign,.lookbook,.portrait").detach()})
$(document).on("click",".loo",function(){$(".campaign,.editorial,.portrait").detach()})
$(document).on("click",".por",function(){$(".campaign,.editorial,.lookbook").detach()})
```

```css
.all,.cam,.edi,.loo,.por {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=all>All</div>
<div class=cam>Campaign</div>
<div class=edi>Editorial</div>
<div class=loo>Lookbook</div>
<div class=por>Portrait</div><br>

<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
```

Comment: Check this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026386/temporarily-removing-and-later-reinserting-a-dom-element

Comment: And why can't you just hide them, it would make it a lot easier than using [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar I tried already to clone the element but when I 'append' it nothing happens actually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [temporarily removing and later reinserting a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026386/temporarily-removing-and-later-reinserting-a-dom-element)

Comment: @adeneo just cause I'm using a plugin that doesn't allow hiding or better I can hide but they still be visible.

Comment: Well, when you use detach you have to store a reference, as in `var elem = $('#id').detach()`

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/wingsofwind/g579m7ux/

You can collect removed elements into array than remove them by using **remove()**

You can **append** them back into the body later on.

```js
/* remove all*/

var allelements = [];  
$("div").each(function(){
  allelements.push($(this));  // we push all divs into an array than remove them
  $(this).remove();
});


/* add back */
setTimeout(function(){ // You can remove This

for(var i = 0 ; i<allelements.length; i++){
    $("body").append(allelements[i]); // we append all elements back into body 
}

},1000) // also remove This
```

```css
.all,.cam,.edi,.loo,.por {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=all>All</div>
<div class=cam>Campaign</div>
<div class=edi>Editorial</div>
<div class=loo>Lookbook</div>
<div class=por>Portrait</div><br>

<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
<div class=campaign>CAMPAIGN</div>
<div class=editorial>EDITORIAL</div>
<div class=lookbook>LOOKBOOK</div>
<div class=portrait>PORTRAIT</div>
```

Comment: @Federico this remove all context than add it back after 1 second if you crop parts individually you can use them

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible by using temporary variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var toBeDeleted = $('.p-tag');
 $('#buttonRemove').on('click',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(toBeDeleted).remove();
 });
 $('#buttonAdd').on('click',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('body').find('.p-tag').length == 0) {
   $('body').append(toBeDeleted);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="" id="buttonRemove">Remove</button>
<button type="button" class="" id="buttonAdd">Add</button>
<p class="p-tag">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```