# How can i add attribut "id" on <img> when i click the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a website where there are some images that I want to add an `id` attribute to it when I click it. For more detail se my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="content" id="select">
        </br>
        <p class="choose_print">Choose Your Photo</p><br/>
        <img src="url......">
        <img src="url......">
        <img src="url......">
        <img src="url......">
        <img src="url......">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#select img').on('click', function (event) {
            $('#select img').css('border', 'none');
            $(event.currentTarget).css('border', 'solid #00a9c6 2px');

            $(event.currentTarget).setAttribute('id','selected'); // how can I add attribute 'id' because it code doesn't work
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `this.id = "someValue"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set new id with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779300/set-new-id-with-jquery)

Comment: In jQuery you should use `prop()` or `attr()` to do this. Alternatively avoid jQuery and just use `event.currentTarget.setAttribute('id','selected')` It should also be noted that dynamically changing `id` attributes is a very bad idea - to the point where I'd say it's an anti-pattern. You should use `class` attributes instead.

Comment: oke thank you, its work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAttribute()` is native elements method. Thus its not working.

```
event.currentTarget.setAttribute('id','selected');
```

Using jQuery you need `.attr()`/`.prop()` methods

```
$(event.currentTarget).attr('id','selected');
```

Comment: so you think it doesn't have duplicate ?

Comment: how can i convert jquery object to native elements ??

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, you already have `event.currentTarget`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what if i use `$(event.currentTarget)`  and want to use native elements method.

Comment: Then that's completely redundant. You'd be starting with a native element, wrapping it in a jQuery object then trying to get the native element back out again.